# Treeline : Error on custom machine cannot read property 'models' of undefined

Tags: sails.js, treeline

I have a runtime exception problem when using a custom machine:

I created a custom machine that accepts three parameters: an array , an id and a create crud machine. It aims to loop over the array and call the machine with the elements of the array and the id, i used the loop machine as inspiration but i got an error 500.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined
at Object.module.exports.fn (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/machines/_project_2294_0.0.5/create_ntag.js:37:14)
at _runMachine (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:336:17)
at afterCacheLookup (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:347:7)
at _cacheLookup (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:160:25)
at Machine_prototype_exec [as exec] (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:211:5)
at /Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/machines/_project_2294_0.0.5/bulkcreateNtags.js:57:29
at /Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/machines/_project_2294_0.0.5/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:125:13
at Array.forEach (native)
at _each (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/machines/_project_2294_0.0.5/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:46:24)
at async.each (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/machines/_project_2294_0.0.5/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:124:9)
at Object.module.exports.fn (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/machines/_project_2294_0.0.5/bulkcreateNtags.js:51:5)
at _runMachine (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:336:17)
at afterCacheLookup (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:347:7)
at _cacheLookup (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:160:25)
at Machine_prototype_exec [as exec] (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/node_modules/machine/lib/Machine.prototype.exec.js:211:5)
at Object.Machine.build.fn (/Users/dev/Desktop/workspace/trifago/api/controllers/TagswithquestionidController.js:30:20) [TypeError: Cannot read property 'models' of undefined]
```

Here is my machine :

```
module.exports = {
  "inputs": {
   "tags": {
   "id": "ce459bad-8a34-4d31-88d1-356bce99a427",
   "friendlyName": "tags",
   "description": "tags to be inserted",
   "typeclass": "array",
   "required": true,
   "addedManually": true
 },
 "questionid": {
   "id": "460b6d0a-296c-467a-b9f4-31849c414be9",
   "friendlyName": "question id",
   "description": "",
   "example": 1,
   "required": true,
   "addedManually": true
 },
 "worker": {
   "id": "d0dce741-1a7b-43c5-b45d-3b7cf11d2bf3",
   "friendlyName": "worker",
   "description": "",
   "typeclass": "machine",
   "required": true,
   "addedManually": true
    }
  },
"exits": {
  "error": {
    "example": undefined
  },
  "success": {
  "void": true,
  "friendlyName": "then",
  "variableName": "result",
  "description": "Normal outcome."
}
  },
   "defaultExit": "success",
  "fn": function(inputs, exits, env) {
  var async = require('async');

  if (!inputs.worker.inputs || typeof inputs.worker.inputs != 'object') {
    return exits.error("Worker misconfigured: no inputs object found");
  }
  var workerInputs = Object.keys(inputs.worker.inputs);
  if (workerInputs.length === 0) {
    return exits.error("Worker misconfigured: inputs object empty");
  }
  var loop = async.each;
  loop(inputs.tags, function(item, cb) {
    var config = {};
    config[workerInputs[0]] = item;
    config[workerInputs[1]] = inputs.questionid;
    config[workerInputs[2]] = 17;

    inputs.worker(config).exec(cb);
   }, exits);
   },
   "identity": "bulkcreateNtags"
  };
```

the line with the error is create_ntag.js:37 the code:

```
env.sails.models.ntag.create(env.sails.util.objCompact(inputs)).exec(function(err, records) {
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What machine are you using for the "worker" when you get this error?

Comment: create Ntag generated by treeline